# Forma eficiente de conectarse a una BD externa

Tags: android

Estoy creando una aplicación en Android.
Tengo un `TextAutoCompleteView`.

¿Qué será mejor en rendimiento para la aplicación?

1. Traer un JSON con la consulta que necesito a la base de datos y cargarla a una lista, para luego compararla con el `TextAutoCompleteView` (la consulta puede traer 2000 Registros)
2. Crear un web services, con una sentencia LIKE, y que este se consuma cada vez que coloco una letra en el TextAutoCompleteView, y me muestre las coincidencias.

Comment: En mi opinión lo mejor que puedes hacer es traer los 2.000 registros cuando inicias la aplicación, guardarlos en la base de datos local y posteriormente consultar la misma con una sentencia like. Si haces una petición para una consulta cada vez que cambias una letra dentro de tu elemento, seria un desperdicio tanto de datos moviles como de procesamiento tanto en servidor como en tu movil, ademas asi tendras un muchisimo mejor rendimiento en velocidad de respuesta por parte de tu app. Espero te sea de utilidad.

Comment: Voto para cerrar esta pregunta ya que cualquier respuesta sería basada en opiniones. Las dos formas que planteas son posibles y puede haber muchas otras formas más. Todo dependerá del contexto, de los recursos, de la cantidad de usuarios y de muchos otros factores. Abramos otro frente de posible solución: `Firebase`... nos ofrece un nuevo abanico de posibilidades, pero siempre la respuesta dependerá de muchas cosas y un solo factor, como por ejemplo, que los datos cambien constantemente, o que estés dispuesto a pagar o no, inclinaría la balanza por una solución u otra.